# How to remove the breadcrumbs while using Active Admin gem in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I have been using `Active admin` gem and want to remove the `breadcrumbs` from `Admin` dashboard. To achieve this I referred [this blog](http://reverbhq.com/blog/2012/08/building-web-apps-with-activeadmin/) to customize `TitleBar`.

I did following steps:

1. Created my own class `MyTitleBar` and copied content of `TitleBar` class from [`active_admin/views/title_bar.rb`](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/37adda1d1491bc71d985816a5e94c309ec382cb7/lib/active_admin/views/title_bar.rb).
2. Removed `build_breadcrumb` line in method `build_titlebar_left`.
3. Removed whole method `build_breadcrumb`.
4. Updated active admin config as:

   config.view_factory.title_bar = MyTitleBar

This works fine.

**My Questions:**

1. Is this the right way to achieve above task?
2. Also, is there any way to remove `breadcrumbs` model-wise?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While that solution may work, it's certainly less than ideal. I noticed looking at the ActiveAdmin gem that their is a configuration option for [breadcrumb](http://rubydoc.info/github/gregbell/active_admin/ActiveAdmin/DSL%3abreadcrumb):

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do

  breadcrumb do
    [
      link_to('my piece', '/my/link/to/piece')
    ]
  end
end
```

It looks like it takes a code block, which is returned to a `links` variable. Looking at [TitleBar::build_breadcrumb](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/views/title_bar.rb), if this configuration option isn't defined, it just sets `links` to the result of `breadcrumb_links()`. Finally, if some type of links array is there, it formats it for printing. Otherwise, the method returns nothing.

So to solve your problem, try writing a code block that returns nil or an empty. I haven't tested this, but something along the lines of the code block below. The idea is that if you feed the variable nil, it should not pass the `links.present?` test and should return immediately, not building the undesired breadcrumb HTML. Alternatively an empty array should fit the type it expects, but without any items nothing should be displayed. I'd need to test locally to see which works better on the frontend.

`/config/initializers/active_admin.rb`:

```
# Return a Proc that simply returns an empty array
config.breadcrumb = Proc.new{ [] }
```

Comment: I have tried the above locally. Seems to work like a charm! Exactly what i was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: You can also use `config.breadcrumb = false` to disable breadcrumbs on a specific page/resource